# como hacer una consulta update sql correctamente

Tags: sql, stored-procedure

Estoy armando un procedimiento almacenado  para actualizar unos datos de una tabla pero cuando actualizo se ejecuta correctamente pero no escribe nada sobre la base de datos

```
USE [qappdotnet]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[webhook]    Script Date: 10/23/2018 18:11:46 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[webhook]
 @Email varchar (500),
  @Saldo varchar(8),
  @Coins varchar(2000)
AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON 

 Declare @Confirma varchar(500)
 SELECT DISTINCT @Confirma =  COUNT (*) from Usuarios where Email=@Email

if(@Confirma <> 1)

 begin

UPDATE qappdotnet.dbo.Usuarios
SET Saldo=@Saldo,Coins = @Coins
WHERE Email=@Email;

Select @Confirma as Respuesta
 end


 if(@Confirma = 1)
 begin
 Select @Confirma as Respuesta
 end


END
```

Comment: Presiento que los valores que le pasas al procedimiento almacenado, lo haces de manera erronea y mas en especifico puede que sea @Email. Checa si lo que llega almacenar esta variable puede empatar en realidad con el campo <Email> de tu tabla.

Comment: pienso que si ya que ambas son variables varchar (500) .. tendra que ver que la columna Email es  la que trae la llave primaria?

Comment: Otro detalle tu procedimiento si llega a ejecutar alguna de las dos condiciones que tienes alli?
Porque probablemente al hacer estas comparaciones:
if(@Confirma <> 1)
Tendrías que hacerlo asi
if(@Confirma <> '1')
Ya que estas comparando cadenas con numeros y debe ser cadenas con cadenas.
Desconozco el motor de base de datos que estes utilizando

Comment: estoy usando sql server 2008 r2  lo puse asi if(@Confirma <> '1') y el resultado fue el mismo